# Does conditional property of React component impact Performance?

Tags: performance, reactjs

Imagine simple React component connected to Redux, which renders DOM node with value from redux store.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ text: state.text })
const Text = connect(mapStateToProps)(({ text }) => text)
return default Text

<Text />
```

Now I want to add `modifier` property to Text component, which adds one `if` statement to `mapStateToProps`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const text = state.text 
  return { text: modifier ? modifier(text) : text }
}

<Text modifier={foo => foo + 2}/>
```

The question is whether I should have two different components or one with `if` inside `mapStateToProps`. My application is heavy loaded data driven app where `store` could be updated several times per second. 50% of `Text` components require modifier, the other 50% do not.

Please advice. Thank You.

Comment: My gut feeling says calling a modifier-function should perform better than an extra react-component in your tree. I'm not sure though and would suggest to try them both.

Comment: Questions like this are hard to answer w/o actual profiling on real data and real component tree. Vote to close.